How would I spoof TTL on a Linux hotspot?
I am currently in a situation in which I have a laptop running a relatively standard Linux setup (Arch with NetworkManager) connected to a network via Ethernet and I am trying to use it's Wi-Fi interface as a hotspot for my phone (that's working and not the problem). The problem is, that the network is blocking any packets with TTL that is not 64 or 128.
Is there some way to increase the TTL of all packets on the hotspot up to 64?

How exactly did you verify the network is blocking specific packets that don’t have a specific TTL? That would be very unusual.

@Ramhound It was a widely used trick by mobile carriers who don't want phone tethering to be used (especially back when phones only had a single APN configuration for both uses). There even used to be tutorials for doing this spoofing via iptables.

@Ramhound Mostly through reports by other users of the network, most of whom solved the problem by connecting dedicated routers running something like OpenWRT

And of course on OpenWRT, changing TTL packets is better documented

Well, OpenWrt and Arch are just two Linux distros. If they both use the same Linux package to do NAT (most likely nftables nowadays?), then the solution is likely to be about the same. So check how OpenWrt users say to do it and then apply it to your Arch setup. Or is this a matter of you don't really know how Arch is doing NAT or where it likes to keep its NAT config files so you were hoping someone familiar with Arch would provide step-by-step instructions specific to Arch?

I don't have the means to verify this, but it should work:
iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -o <WLAN-device> -j TTL --ttl-set 64


Your answer worked for me, but with a small edit (removing the -o argument). iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -j TTL --ttl-set 64
